# Casting vs Duplicate Code: What is the best of two given options?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

**The situation (UML given below):** A java package shall have a class *Process* that runs a calculation in a loop within a thread and notifies observers about the result of that calculation. A new calculation is initiated bei adding a value from outside the class to a queue the thread can read:

```
public class Process
{
/* ... */
Thread th;
BlockingQueue queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(10);

public void calc()
{
    th = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            {
                try
                {
                    Integer value = (Integer) queue.take();
                    List<Float> result = calculator.calcAllResults(value);
                    /* ... Do something with result ...*/
                } catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void addValue(Integer value)
{
    queue.add(value);
}
/* ... */
}
```

The calculation itself in *calcAllResults(int value)* is as follows: The calculator object has a (interchangeable by a config file, not fixed) list of "smaller calculators" that calculate exactly one Float in the result list. Now, the calculator object first gathers some data and then just runs all the small calculators in a loop:

```
public class Calculator
{
/* ... */

private DataGatherer1 dataGatherer1;

public List<Float> calcAllResults(int value)
{
    List<Float> result = new List<Float>();
    DataType1 dt1 = dataGatherer1.getData(value);
    for (int i = 0; i < calculators.size(); i++)
    {
        result.add(calculators.get(i).calcSingleResult(dt1));
    }
}

/* ... */
}
```

**My Problem:** For the moment there is only one way to calculate the result, but in future there will be more. That means: Currently, the small calculator objects that run *calcSingleResult* depend on data of type *DataType1* (see listing above), but in future there might be another set of calculator objects that depend on data of type *DataType2*. Of course, then there must be another class, *DataGatherer2*, that gathers data of that new type. In order to make the code expandable in the way mentioned, I thought of two options how to design the package. But none of them seem to be satisfactory for the reasons mentioned below. To make the two approches clear, I made two UML-Diagrams:

[Design1](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3596/vbt68s9u_jpg.htm)
[Design2](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3596/zppioqq9_jpg.htm)

**Design 1:**

The calculator for calculating the result list has an *AbstractDataGatherer* object which can be of type *DataGatherer1* or *DataGatherer2* (depending on the state of the program). As both data types (*DataType1* and *DataType2*) are of type *AbstractDataObject*, the method calcAllResults() can have all the logic for gathering data and calculation (an **advantage** of this design (?)), no matter what set of *CalcType's* is in its calculator list:

```
public class Calculator
{
/* ... */

private AbstractDataGatherer dataGatherer;
private List<AbstractCalculationType> calculators;

public List<Float> calcAllResults(int value)
{
    List<Float> result = new List<Float>();
    AbstractDataObject dt = dataGatherer.getData(value);
    for (int i = 0; i < calculators.size(); i++)
    {
        result.add(calculators.get(i).calcSingleResult(dt));
    }
}

/* ... */
}
```

The **disadvantage** is (in my eyes) that a specific CalcType expects a specific DataType in its *calcSingleResult*()-routine. So *AbstractDataObject dt* must be casted. For example:

```
public class CalcType1A extends AbstractCalculationType
{
/* ... */

private DataType1 data;

public float calcSingleResult(AbstractDataObject data)
{
    this.data = (DataType1) data;
}

/* ... */
}
```

**Design 2:**

The *calcAllResults()*-method is now inside an object of type *AbstractCalculationStrategy*. From this abstract class two (in future possibly more) subclasses exist: *CalculationStrategy1* and *CalculationStrategy2*. Both define *calcAllResults()* alone. For example:

```
public class CalculationStrategy1 extends AbstractCalculationStrategy
{
/* ... */

private DataGatherer1 dataGatherer1;
private List<AbstractCalculationType1> calculators; 

public float calcAllResult(int value)
{
    List<Float> result = new List<Float>();
    DataType1 dt1 = dataGatherer1.getData(value);
    for (int i = 0; i < calculators.size(); i++)
    {
        result.add(calculators.get(i).calcSingleResult(dt1));
    }
}

/* ... */
}
```

(The same for *CalculationStrategy2*, but with a *DataGatherer2* object and *AbstractCalculationType2* objects instead.)

This is basically the situation from above where only one calculation type existed. The **advantage** here is that each strategy must gather a specific data type that its calculator objects really wants (no cast). The **disadvantage** is that you have duplicate code: The logic in the method *calcAllResult()* is the same (or: must in future be implemented in the same way) for both (in future possible more) calculation strategies. Additionally the UML diagram shows that there is a symmetry that I would like to prevent with OOP-means, because OOP is made to prevent duplicate code / symmetry, right?

So, what is the best design? Or are both options not okay?

Comment: Did you consider using generics for your DataType? AbstractCalculationType<T extends DataType> where DataType1 extends DataType, So yo get CalcType1A extends AbstractCalculationType<DataType1> for instance and you get no cast problem.

Comment: Using generics solved the problem! Thanks a lot!